# How 'Sys._application' javascript error suddenly came up?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scriptmanager

A javascript error suddenly came up throughout all files containing `<asp:ScriptManager..>`, error message is as below,

> Error: Sys.ArgumentTypeException:
>   OBject of type 'Sys_Application'
>   cannot be converted to type
>   'Sys._Application'/ Parameter name:
>   instance

I resolved the issue by adding 'ScriptMode="Release"' to ScriptManager, but I don't think it's a best solution, seems like a quick-fix, I really need to know how and why did this error occur. I can assure you that I didn't change any line of code, I even use file-compare tool to affirm it.

What's happened? and how to solve it without change as `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"  ScriptMode ="Release"/>` ?

Elaine

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Smart Navigation enabled for the page? If you do try turning it off (if you don't need it) and it should fix it hopefully.